# Bash Script to check host status

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file 1.txt which has one line per ip or host, ie:

```
yahoo.com
8.8.8.8
```

I am trying to write a bash script that will parse through this text file to see if host is up or not. I need it to store the status of the host on namesake text file and loop the process indefinitely.

Here is my progress so far, somehow it doesnt seem to be working, not sure why.

```
while read ip ; do
        ping -c 1 $ip | grep -E -o '[0-9]+ received' | cut -f1 -d' ' > $ip-status 
$STATUS=$(cat $ip-status)
if [ $STATUS = "1" ]; then
                echo "$ip is UP"
fi
echo "$ip is DOWN!"
done < 1.txt
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working? That's not very informative. What happens when you run the script? Do you get any error messages? What do they say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not take a different approach and do something like this:

```
while true; 
do 
    for i in $(cat test); 
    do  
        dig +short +timeout=2 +tries=3 "$i" && 
        echo "$i" is up || 
        echo "$i" is not responding; 
        sleep 2; 
     done; 
done;
```

Here is the tested output:

```
$ while true; do for i in $(cat test); do dig +short +timeout=2 "$i" && echo host "$i" is up || echo host "$i" is not responding; sleep 2; done; done
216.58.218.206
host google.com is up
98.138.253.109
98.139.183.24
206.190.36.45
host yahoo.com is up
216.58.218.206
host google.com is up
206.190.36.45
98.138.253.109
98.139.183.24
host yahoo.com is up
216.58.218.206
host google.com is up
98.139.183.24
206.190.36.45
98.138.253.109
host yahoo.com is up
```

If you do not want the IPs like this then you could sent the standard output to /dev/null.

Please up vote if you found this helpful.

## Edit:

I forgot to show you my test file:

```
$ cat test
google.com
yahoo.com
$
```